# SVN under eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to know how to cleanly create an svn project in eclipse.

I did it badly.  Tell me what I'm doing wrong:
First, I copied the files up to the server.

I take all the code, in directory draw2
mkdir branches logs trunk
all the code is put into trunk

1. Create the directory with
   svnadmin create /var/svn/draw2
2. Import it with

svn import ~/draw2 file:///var/svn/draw2 -m "initial import"

Using tortoise svn, I can check out a clean copy, it seems to be there.
But then I want to use eclipse.
installed  Svnkit plugins

3. create a new project in eclipse, from svn.  It downloads the project
   where before, there was a src directory, now there is a trunk/src

zillions of errors.

Is there any clean way for me to just upload a project, as is in eclipse, and then check it out on other machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Create project in Eclipse. 
(2) Right click
(3) Select Team->Share Project
(4) Follow the wizard